# Azure AD Grant Permissions to Custom-Developed Application with Headless Login

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a headless login for an AAD Authorized application that takes user credentials and passes them to Microsoft for Authorization/Authentication. I followed [this applications design Microsoft provided on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless).

I am attempting to perform Admin Consent for my application so the users do not get a prompt. I have followed the directions that [Microsoft Provided here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/application-dev-registration-config-grant-permissions-how-to#how-to-perform-admin-consent-for-your-application) but the AdalException from the Login comes back with the following error message with an "invalid_grant" ErrorCode:

> AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'GUID' named 'ApplicationName'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

When a user or admin go into Azure AD App Registrations blade, then Required Permissions, and hit "Grant Permissions" that specific person that clicked the button, Global Admin or not, are granted access to the application through the login. It has not been granting it for all users in Active Directory as the Microsoft directions imply.

Using a headless login is required because the users credentials are stored in Windows Credential Manager and any software in the suite uses the same credentials and being prompted on each application is best to be avoided. At all costs I'm trying to prevent a user prompt for login beyond the initial credential input that saves them to the Credential Manager. How can I achieve a headless login for all my users?

Comment: I'm not sure why the Grant is not going through, but I also want to make sure of one thing. Are you aware of the limitations of the approach that you use? I.e. ROPC grant flow. If the user has MFA enabled or if they are a federated user or if their password expires the logins will fail.

Comment: The problem with the Grant not going through is the user was not a Gobal Admin as thought.
You bring up really great limitations and points of discussion. I'm assuming setting the prompt behavior, like in the other azure examples, would provide solutions for MFA and Password Expiration?

Comment: Every single way which does the login interactively will work in all those cases.

Comment: @JustinNeff Is the the answer to the question? "The problem with the Grant not going through is the user was not a Gobal Admin as thought."

Comment: Yes, I will add the the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the grant not going through is the user was not a Gobal Admin.
Verify the user clicking on "Grant Permission" has admin. Otherwise there is a way to generate a querystring for an admin prompting login, [an example of what to do lives here.](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/01/24/Admin-Consent-for-Permissions-in-Azure-Active-Directory.aspx)